# Mistakes in calculation found after submission of a manuscript

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted a paper recently to a journal. In that paper I showed some calculations and compared some experimental results with the calculations. The calculations show good agreement with the experimental results. After submitting the paper I realized that there are some mistakes in the representation of some equations in the calculation but the final result of the calculations is correct because these are some standard calculations which have been done by other authors previously with some variations. Now I don't know what to do ? Will the paper be rejected ?

Answer (score 5):

It might be rejected as any paper might be. Contact the editor, pointing out that there are errors that you don't believe affect the outcome. Ask for advice. You might be able to withdraw the paper and then submit a corrected version, but the editor will have advice.

Another possibility is that reviewers will suggest corrections for a revised version. This isn't the first such incident that the editor has dealt with.

"It ain't over 'til its over" (Famous NY advice from Yogi Berra).